# "cannot find original pch source file" while running oclint-xcodebuild manually

Tags: ios, terminal, xcodebuild, oclint

So I am using Xcode version 6.3.1 and I am trying to run OClint manually using the link [here](http://docs.oclint.org/en/dev/guide/xcodebuild.html)

So when first time I followed the process I was able to generate **compile_commands.json** successfully using **"oclint-xcodebuild"** and while running **"oclint-json-compilation-database"** I was stuck for long so I tried rerunning **"oclint-xcodebuild"** deleting the **compile_commands.json** file and now I am not able to.

The commandline shows this error 
**"cannot find original pch source file for /var/folders/b_/7xppkkm52111c6pxwcm48k2sd8zptt/C/com.apple.DeveloperTools/6.2-6C131e/Xcode/SharedPrecompiledHeaders/AppX_Prefix-epekrudleryecuadzxmiivcciajs/project_Prefix.pch"**

I tried cleaning build.. Doing everyrthing but not much help available online. i am not using cocoapods

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ohkk here what i did so I went to the **"/var/folders/b_/7xppkkm52111c6pxwcm48k2sd8zptt/C/com.apple.DeveloperTools/6.2-6C131e/Xcode/SharedPrecompiledHeaders/AppX_Prefix-epekrudleryecuadzxmiivcciajs"** path or wherever youer path is and delete all the pch files in the folder with certain extentions.

Delete **xcodebuild.log** and **compile_commands.json** and now start with generating the log file again with the whole flow.

It worked :)